# Unable to Install Nuget Manager extension on Visual Studio 2010 Phone Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-express

I am using **Visual Studio 2010 for Phone Express** to develop Windows Phone 7 apps. Unfortunately, it does not come installed with **Nuget Manager**. So based on the content ***[at this site](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c)***, I downloaded the **VSIX installer** for  **Visual Studio 2010 for Phone Express** from this ***[link](https://nuget.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1441481)***

Unfortunately, the installer fails with error

[image: Install Error]

I am posting the relevant section of the install Log.

```
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -   Supported Products : 
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -           Version : [10.0]
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -           Version : [11.0]
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -           Version : [10.0]
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -           Version : [11.0]
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.VPDExpress
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -           Version : [10.0]
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.VPDExpress
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -           Version : [11.0]
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.VWDExpress
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -           Version : [11.0]
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinExpress
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -           Version : [11.0]
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinDesktopExpress
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -           Version : [11.0]
14-04-2015 18:38:22 - 
14-04-2015 18:38:22 -   References      : 
14-04-2015 18:38:22 - 
14-04-2015 18:38:22 - Searching for applicable products...
14-04-2015 18:38:22 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone
14-04-2015 18:38:22 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013
14-04-2015 18:38:22 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
14-04-2015 18:38:22 - Found installed product - Global Location
14-04-2015 18:38:22 - Found installed product - ssms
14-04-2015 18:38:22 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

As can be seen from logs, it does discover the Visual Studio Phone Developer 2010 Express, but still aborts the installation of the extension.

Can anyone please help me out with the installation of **Nuget Manager** on **Visual Studio 2010 Express for Phone**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest Update for Visual Studio 2010 Express for Phone!
But I think that the express editions do not support extensions so VsVim cannot be installed.

Though they [recently enabled](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2086051-allow-extensions-plugins-for-vs-express) extensions/plugins for VS Express. But I think that is just available for Version 13

Comment: I checked for updates and I don't have any pending updates for Visual Studio 2010. So, I guess I am running the latest version. I think generally the extensions are not allowed on Visual Studio 2010, but [The Extension Site](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c) lists extension specifically for **Visual Studio 2010 Phone Express**. That's what made me believe, that this extension can be installed on the Express version too.