# Nuget Package Manager Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-7.1

I can not install NuGet Package Manager  - after downloading and doubleclicking it writes:

> This extension is not installable on any currently installed
>   products

please help me I want to instal for visual studio 2010 phone express.

Comment: There is already a thread about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628511/unable-to-install-nuget-manager-extension-on-visual-studio-2010-phone-express

Comment: thanks bt  how to get  latest Update for Visual Studio 2010 Express for Phone so wat is d perfct solution for it ..aftr getting downloaded form this link http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases am always getting error

Answer (score 0):

first navigate to Package Manager Console and then write the following in the package manager console

```
PM> Get-Package -updates
```

this will give you list of all updates available, then use the following command to update the required package

```
PM> Update-Package <package name>
```